# How to publish dotnetnuke website to azure?

Tags: azure, web, dotnetnuke, publish

I am looking at migrating a dotnetnuke website to Azure. I need both staging and production versions of the site to be running.

I have looked at using Azure Websites, but at the moment there is no support for SSL on custom domains so this can't be used for the production website. I have migrated the staging site to an Azure Website and now have numerous options for publishing updates (ftp, git, using web matrix).

Due to the constraints of Azure Websites, I used the DNN Accelerator to create a cloud service for the production environment. This set up will allow me to have control over IIS and therefore manage SSL certificates (I think).

The problem I have with this is there does not seem to be any publishing options. The only way I can publish is by connecting to the Azure instance via RDP and then copying the website files onto the files system.

Are there any other ways of publishing? I have looked at converting the website to a WAP, but I believe this has implications when it comes to updating to new DNN versions.

Answer (score 1):

You should never publish your application through RDP since these changes are non-persistent (meaning what you published might disappear after a hardware failure / ...). Adding new instances would also mean that these instances don't have the files you published before.

I suggest you start by looking at the [DotNetNuke Azure Accelerator](http://dnnazureaccelerator.codeplex.com/) first. If this doesn't fit your needs you might always try to build something yourself, but if you want to say with a regular website and not a web application I wouldn't count on Visual Studio support. In that case you might want to look at [creating a package from the command line](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/building-running-and-packaging-windows-azure-applications-from-the-command-line) and using startup scripts to add your website in IIS.

Comment: I used the Azure accelerator to create the cloud service. I think the files that IIS is serving up are on blob storage, so I think these will be persistent? I will take a look at creating a package from command line. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, blob storage is persistent. Also, you'll see that the accelerator also uses XDrive, but this is simply a VHD in blob storage, so this is also persistent.

Comment: So that means it's ok to publish the website through rdp since it is being saved in blob storage?

Comment: You could RDP to the SMB Server and make modifications there (as described here: http://dnnazureaccelerator.codeplex.com/discussions/278296). But I think a real deployment is way cleaner (you can automate this using PowerShell for example).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use a Start-up task to install the files in the correct place for a Web Role (Cloud Service) Smarx has a nice overview here, MSDN has a wealth of info too http://blog.smarx.com/posts/introduction-to-windows-azure-startup-tasks

Another option is IAAS for Azure with a persisted VM, more work mind you, Cloud Service would be the most efficient and correct solution...